# Iterating through an array of objects with nested array to determine required result

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, nested-loops

Given the following array of objects structure, I needs a means of scanning all object elements within this array, i.e. Monday to Sunday and returning a boolean (true) if atleast one entry has the:

`weeklyFlag` set to true and both `weeklyStartTime` and `weeklyEndTime` are not null - have a date value against them.

In the data below, Monday's `weeklyFlag` is set to true but it's other data isn't whereas Tuesday has all the required criteria to return a true result.

In the end, I just need to check for one object to have all the data set.

Was looking at nested for loops but unsure if array `map` or `filter` can be used?

```
let weeklyTimes = [
                    {
                        "day": "Monday",
                        "startEnd": [
                            {
                                "weeklyFlag": true,
                                "weeklyStartTime": null,
                                "weeklyEndTime": null
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "day": "Tuesday",
                        "startEnd": [
                            {
                                "weeklyFlag": true,
                                "weeklyStartTime": "2021-08-08T14:00:00.000Z",
                                "weeklyEndTime": "2021-08-08T15:00:00.000Z"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "day": "Wednesday",
                        "startEnd": [
                            {
                                "weeklyFlag": false,
                                "weeklyStartTime": null,
                                "weeklyEndTime": null
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "day": "Thursday",
                        "startEnd": [
                            {
                                "weeklyFlag": false,
                                "weeklyStartTime": null,
                                "weeklyEndTime": null
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "day": "Friday",
                        "startEnd": [
                            {
                                "weeklyFlag": false,
                                "weeklyStartTime": null,
                                "weeklyEndTime": null
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "day": "Saturday",
                        "startEnd": [
                            {
                                "weeklyFlag": false,
                                "weeklyStartTime": null,
                                "weeklyEndTime": null
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "day": "Sunday",
                        "startEnd": [
                            {
                                "weeklyFlag": false,
                                "weeklyStartTime": null,
                                "weeklyEndTime": null
                            }
                        ]
                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.filter()` to filter the data as followings.

Btw, `startEnd` attribute may be an object instead of an array since it has only 1 item.

```js
let weeklyTimes = [{ "day": "Monday", "startEnd": [{ "weeklyFlag": true, "weeklyStartTime": null, "weeklyEndTime": null }] }, { "day": "Tuesday", "startEnd": [{ "weeklyFlag": true, "weeklyStartTime": "2021-08-08T14:00:00.000Z", "weeklyEndTime": "2021-08-08T15:00:00.000Z" }] }, { "day": "Wednesday", "startEnd": [{ "weeklyFlag": false, "weeklyStartTime": null, "weeklyEndTime": null }] }, { "day": "Thursday", "startEnd": [{ "weeklyFlag": false, "weeklyStartTime": null, "weeklyEndTime": null }] }, { "day": "Friday", "startEnd": [{ "weeklyFlag": false, "weeklyStartTime": null, "weeklyEndTime": null }] }, { "day": "Saturday", "startEnd": [{ "weeklyFlag": false, "weeklyStartTime": null, "weeklyEndTime": null }] }, { "day": "Sunday", "startEnd": [{ "weeklyFlag": false, "weeklyStartTime": null, "weeklyEndTime": null }] }]

const filteredData = weeklyTimes.filter((day) =>
  day.startEnd[0].weeklyFlag
  && day.startEnd[0].weeklyStartTime
  && day.startEnd[0].weeklyEndTime)

console.log(filteredData)
```

---

Or you can use `Array.find()` if you want only 1 item to be returned

```js
let weeklyTimes = [{ "day": "Monday", "startEnd": [{ "weeklyFlag": true, "weeklyStartTime": null, "weeklyEndTime": null }] }, { "day": "Tuesday", "startEnd": [{ "weeklyFlag": true, "weeklyStartTime": "2021-08-08T14:00:00.000Z", "weeklyEndTime": "2021-08-08T15:00:00.000Z" }] }, { "day": "Wednesday", "startEnd": [{ "weeklyFlag": false, "weeklyStartTime": null, "weeklyEndTime": null }] }, { "day": "Thursday", "startEnd": [{ "weeklyFlag": false, "weeklyStartTime": null, "weeklyEndTime": null }] }, { "day": "Friday", "startEnd": [{ "weeklyFlag": false, "weeklyStartTime": null, "weeklyEndTime": null }] }, { "day": "Saturday", "startEnd": [{ "weeklyFlag": false, "weeklyStartTime": null, "weeklyEndTime": null }] }, { "day": "Sunday", "startEnd": [{ "weeklyFlag": false, "weeklyStartTime": null, "weeklyEndTime": null }] }]

const filteredData = weeklyTimes.find((day) =>
  day.startEnd[0].weeklyFlag
  && day.startEnd[0].weeklyStartTime
  && day.startEnd[0].weeklyEndTime)

console.log(filteredData)
```

Comment: @pilchard - this sounds like what I am after as I need to just find one day that has everything set. Are you able to pls provide an example?

Comment: @pilchard Yes, you're right as OP said `I just need to check for one object to have all the data set` Therefore `Array.find()` will be more proper

Comment: Will the above scan all `startEnd` objects as I see you have specified `startEnd[0]` ?

Comment: @ArthurJ `startEnd` is an array so in order to access the properties of the object, you need to use the index 0. I think it is better to refactor the property to make it and object.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to change this structure, so need to keep it in this format. Based on this, will I need to go down and specify `day.startEnd[1]` , `day.startEnd[2]` etc using `weeklyTimes.find((day)` - is there not an index I can use from array.find ?

Comment: Each `day` has only 1 item in its `startEnd` array. So you can only use `day.startEnd[0]`. Any other indexes will return `undefined`. If you want to get the index of matching day, you can use `Array.findIndex()` instead of `Array.find()`

Comment: Gotcha now. No, I do not need to match any particular day

Comment: Sorry, how can I adjust the weeklyTimes.find to return a boolean if atleast one entry is found?

Comment: `Array.find()` will return `undefined` if no matching value is found. So you can convert the returning value to a boolean by using double exclamation marks like `!!weeklyTimes.find(......)`